# Why can I not use the Unicode characters √ and ∀ in assignments?

Tags: unicode, variable-assignment, julia

Julia has an interesting support for Unicode characters. The syntax allows me to run the following in the iJulia notebook.

```
μ = 10
σ = 20
∑ = sum
a = [1,2,3,4] 
∑(a) # prints 10
```

However, it doesn't always seem like you can use Unicode characters for function/variable names.

#### sqrt √ example

```
√ = sqrt
```

Gives the following error:

```
syntax: unexpected "="
```

#### forall ∀ example

```
forall(x,f) = [f(i) for i in x]
∀ = forall
```

Gives the following error:

```
syntax: invalid character "∀"
```

#### Why?

Am I misunderstand the rules? I assumed that a Unicode character would be interpreted just like any other alphabetical character, but I seem to get two different errors on seemingly simple statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`√` is the name of an existing function; try running the following:

```
julia> methods(√)
# 12 methods for generic function "sqrt":
sqrt(a::Complex{Float16}) at float16.jl:141
sqrt{T<:FloatingPoint}(z::Complex{T<:FloatingPoint}) at complex.jl:237
sqrt(z::Complex{T<:Real}) at complex.jl:261
...
```

As for `∀`, it is not a valid character in Julia source code (yet?). See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/0YC6a0_9Z1Q/Ix8SzCyG1JIJ); what transpires is that the developers are still considering whether to make `∀` a valid character, and if they do, what meaning it would have.

Comment: is there documentation describing what characters are and what characters aren'y accessible in iJulia? I was surprised because the `\forall` tab completion does work ...

Comment: @cantdutch this: Many tab completions work, but don't make valid code. Including `\bar`  to draw a overline. I suggest a issue should be filed with ijulia (if one doesn't already exist).

Comment: @Oxinabox, issue has been filed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that these functions are already defined.

See the link some of the characters that have meanings built into Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d234b4ff56df9ce85198dcdd8d9ef1073b2436fc/base/operators.jl#L403-L432 (note, not all of these are unicode and there might be others in a different file in base -- but this at least covers your `sqrt` example)